# I don't want HSTS on port 8001 but on other ports

Tags: nginx, hsts

I have hsts set for my domain in Nginx.conf . It will redirect my website to https for main port 80. But I don't want the redirect to happen for my other port. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you add/paste the relevant portions of your `nginx.conf` on your question?

Answer (score 1):

Simplified: HSTS is a domain wide policy to that forbids the use of plain http on your domain. That policy is regardless of which port you want to access over plain http, be it the default port 80 or another like 8001.

If you request your domain on
`http://www.example.com` that is effected by rewriting the uri to
`https://www.example.com`

On other ports than port 80 that happens by rewriting plain http requests to https  but maintaining the non-standard port,
`http://www.example.com:8001/page.html` should be rewritten into
`https://www.example.com:8001/page.html`

So as long as you configured port 8001 to support TLS you’re good.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797

```
      The UA MUST replace the URI scheme with "https" [RFC2818], and

      if the URI contains an explicit port component of "80", then
      the UA MUST convert the port component to be "443", or

      if the URI contains an explicit port component that is not
      equal to "80", the port component value MUST be preserved;
      otherwise,

      if the URI does not contain an explicit port component, the UA
      MUST NOT add one.

      NOTE:  These steps ensure that the HSTS Policy applies to HTTP
             over any TCP port of an HSTS Host.
```